# Entity Framework - One to Many relation - mapping to only one element

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My example is like the following:
I've a [Table1] which has one-to-many relation to [Table2].

Let say it looks like:

```
[Table1]:
    [Id] int

[Table2]:
    [Table1Id] int (foreign key to [Table1])
    [UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id] int
```

[Table2] has indeed foreign key to [Table1], and it's possible to have multiple elements in [Table2], that has relation to [Table1].

I know how to define mapping between [Table1] and [Table2] from code, means:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2Objects { get; set; }
}
public class Table1_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Table1>
{
    public class Table1()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Table2Objects).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1);
    }
}
```

But is there a way to define *Entity framework* mapping, where I would specify One-to-many mapping, but only with mapping to **one specific** row from [Table2]? I do have **[UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id]** column at [Table2] which is always unique for given [Table1] - therefore I know, that running something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table1Id] = 123 AND [UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id] = 456
```

will always result with one row queried.

From C# code what I need, is something like:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2Objects { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2 Table2Object456 { get; set; }
}
public class Table1_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Table1>
{
    public class Table1()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Table2Objects).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1);
        this.MagicMethod(x => x.Table2Object456).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1).OtherMagicMethodWhichAllowsToPutFilter(x => x.UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id == 456);
    }
}
```

Of course this fragment is what I need:

```
this.MagicMethod(x => x.Table2Object456).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1).OtherMagicMethodWhichAllowsToPutFilter(x => x.UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id == 456);
```

Comment: What is `MagicMethod` method? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Have you tried to add `using Magic;` in the beginning of your file? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an understanding of what you actually want.

I think you want something like this:

```cs
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set;}

    public virtual Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

EF should automagically make the relationship between PrimaryAddressId and the navigational property.

you don't really want that magic configuration thing... unless you mean to always have the same Address as the PrimaryAddress, then you can do that as a default value instead... but that seems to be a code smell and probably don't want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a **good** option is not to do this, but just create a method in a repository which handles this special case:

```
public class YourRepository
{
    public Table2 Table2WithUniqueColumn456(Table1 table1)
    {
        using var context = new Table1Context();
        return context.Entry(table1)
                      .Collection(t1 => t1.Table2Objects)
                      .Query()
                      .FirstOrDefault(t2 => t2.UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id == 456);
    }
}
```

Now, you can explicitly call this method every time you need to get a `Table2` with this value being equal to 456.

If you are asking for curiousity, then one **bad** option would be to utilize inheritance:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2Objects { get; set; }
    public virtual Table2WithUniqueColumn456 Table2Object456 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table2")]
public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public int UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table2")] // this will tell EF to use table-per-hierarchy
public class Table2WithUniqueColumn456 : Table2
{
}

public class Table1_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Table1>
{
    public class Table1()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Table2Objects).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1);
        this.HasOne(x => x.Table2Object456).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x => x.Table1);
    }
}
```

As you can see:

- You need to handle the creation logic and make sure that all objects with `UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id` 456 are created as `Table2WithUniqueColumn456`
- `UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id` should be immutable or it may bring much more complex logic of editing
- It creates additional column in `Table2`

Perhaps, if there are not so many `Table2` objects per `Table1`, this could be even better way than inheritance, even though it is not that effective:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2Objects { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Table2WithUniqueColumn456 Table2Object456 
    {
        get { return Table2Objects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueColumnAtTable2ForGivenTable1Id == 456; }
    }
}
```